# Getting image from other user

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I'm trying to add a picture from another user and use it as a picture for a new account, using Hibernate.

This is what I have so far:

```
Session newSession = HibernateUtil.getSession();
String newHql = "SELECT picture FROM User WHERE ID = 188";
Query newQuery = newSession.createQuery(newHql);
String newImage = newQuery.toString();
user.setImageString(newImage);
```

The query works when I'm using it in the database itself, but when I'm trying to create a query, by using newHql, I get an error (on the third line of the code shown above):

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'picture' {originalText=picture}
```

The datatype of picture in the database is LONGTEXT, since it represents an encoded String of a .jpg file.

First, I thought the String was too long, but I used it as a String before in my Java application.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't executing the query, you are just using the `toString` method result of the `Query` object.

Execute the query:

```
String newImage = (String) newQuery.uniqueResult();
```